# 'ViewModelProviders' is deprecated. After upgrading lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0 to 2.2.0-alpha05

Tags: android, android-viewmodel, kotlin-android-extensions

Android Studio -> New Project -> Choice "Tabbed Activity".

After upgrading lifecycle-extensions from 2.1.0 to 2.2.0-alpha05 ViewModelProviders is deprecated. 
In simple cases it replaceable by "by viewModels()"
for example:

```
plHlFrModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(PlHlFrModel::class.java)
```

replaced by:

```
private val plHlFrModel by viewModels<PlHlFrModel>()
```

But I can't figure out how to replace this one:

```
pageViewModel =  ViewModelProviders.of(this)
     .get(PageViewModel::class.java).apply {
         setIndex(arguments?.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) ?: 1)
      }
```

where and how to place apply{} block in a "by viewModel" form?
Maybe there is another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ViewModelProviers` is deperecated, we just use [ViewModelProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider.html#ViewModelProvider(androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelStoreOwner,%20androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.Factory)).

#### Direct access

```
pageViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)
     .get(PageViewModel::class.java).apply {
         setIndex(arguments?.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) ?: 1)
      }
```

#### using delegate

```
private val pageViewModel by viewModels<PageViewModel>()

//function scope
pageViewModel.setIndex(arguments?.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) ?: 1)
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using  `ViewModelProviders.of(this)` use `ViewModelProvider(This)
new ViewModelProvider(this).get(Vm.class);` for java

Comment: How can I implement this by Java? ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel.class) not work for Java ('androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0-rc03')

Answer (score 1):

```
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(vm.class); // is deprecate

viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(vm.class); // is true
```

Answer (score 1):

```
viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(vm.class);
```

This will work only with this dependency:

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
```