# 'ViewModelProviders' is deprecated. Java solution?

Tags: android, viewmodel, viewmodelproviders

'ViewModelProviders' is deprecated from androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-*:2.2.0-alpha03
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#2.2.0-alpha03
Here is solution for Kotlin
['ViewModelProviders' is deprecated. After upgrading lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0 to 2.2.0-alpha05](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58146582/viewmodelproviders-is-deprecated-after-upgrading-lifecycle-extensions2-1-0-t)
But what is Java version of that? 
ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel.class) not work for Java.

Comment: They are replacing it with `new ViewModelProvider(this)` for some reason. Tbh the previous variant was better, but it's their lib

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 5):

ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel.class); - deprecated

new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel.class); - correct

Thanks @EpicPandaForce !

Answer (score 1):

Generic Example (up to android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.0). it is deprecated from 1.1.1,

```
MyViewModel myViewModel = new ViewModelProviders.of(this, new MyViewModelFactory(this.getApplication(), "Your string parameter")).get(MyViewModel.class);
```

Generic Example (for android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1)

```
MyViewModel myViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(MyViewModel.class);
```

OR, Use ViewModelStore [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelStore)

```
MyViewModel myViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(getViewModelStore(), viewModelFactory).get(MyViewModel.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a CREATOR object for your ViewModel and call this object from your activity this object will act as a factory object that you can call as you call any ViewModelFactory.

```
ViewModelProviders.of(this, ViewModelFactoryObject).get(ViewModel::class.java).apply{}
```